# Return Base64 Encoded Image As HTTP Response in C#

Tags: c#, image, http, base64

I have a webservice and in this particular case I have an image encoded in base64 that I would like to return as a string included in the http response body. I have tried to add the following headers:

Content-Type: image/gif

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

The browser doesn't interpreted the image correctly though.

Is it possible to return a base64 encoded image as a string in the body and have the browser interpret it as an image?

Answer (score 1):

```
Response.ContentType = attachmentRow["ContentType"].ToString();
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])attachmentRow["Data"]);                
Response.End();
```

This should be enough.

```
attachmentRow["ContentType"] = "image/gif";
attachmentRow["Data"] field of type image(byte array) in your AttachmentTable.
```

Comment: My images no longer show up as a bunch of text when someone right-clicks and goes to open them in a new tab. I can't believe it was that easy.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Content-Transfer-Encoding in HTTP. Just return the binary data.